# Issue enabling HDRI for ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, hdrimages

I am installing ImageMagick on my server and upon entering the following config command:

```
    ./configure --enable-hdri
```

I get an output for the configuration that shows:

```
    --enable-hdri=yes       yes
```

But, when I try:

```
    identify -version
```

Am am given:

```
    Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2010-11-16 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
    Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
    Features: OpenMP
```

With HDRI missing from the Features section.

Anyone know what gives? Thanks!

Comment: Which operating system is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run

```
which identify
```

to see where your called `identify` binary is located:

- Is this really the one you have compiled and installed?
- Or is it rather another one (which pre-dates your own build and which wasn't cleanly removed)?
- You may be able to 'fix' this by tweaking your `$PATH` variable, or by calling the `identify` you really want with its full path...